# limits multivariable calculus. where am i wrong with my attempt?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, self-learning

P : $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ where
$$f(x,y) = y\sin\frac1x + \frac{xy}{x^{2} + y^{2}}$$

Text book says Limit doesnot exist . So where i am wrong with my proof below ?

EDITED ATTEMPT :
[image]

Or we can write $2 \delta < \varepsilon$, which shows limit exists. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y>y^2$ for $y\in(0,1)$, which is the source of mistake.

Putting $y=cx$ gives 
$$
cx\sin(1/x)+\frac{c}{1+c^2}
$$ 
and the limit in 0 certainly doesn't exist, because the first term tends to 0.

Comment: Thanks.what is problem is  absolute value of $y/x^{2}+y^{2}$ less than equal to 1

Comment: If $y<y^2$ for $y\in(0,1)$ then the inequality is true

Comment: @godonichia Of course there shold be $y>y^2$. Corrected. And   $\lim_{y\to0}|y/y^2|=\infty$, hence certainly cannot be less than 1.

Comment: If $y<y^2$ for $y\in(0,1)$  then denominator is bigger than numerator so it s less than 1

Comment: I am not talking about limit . im estimation the ratio

Comment: @godonichia But $y>y^2$ **always** on $(0,1)$. Please try to sketch graph of these functions.

Comment: Ok i understand , But how  is contribution of of x^{2} effects in denominator and u have choosen (0,1) bcos we have to find limit at (o,o) . Also check first line of ur answer .

Comment: I think i have got ur point now . Just confirm that u have taken disc of unit radius around origin

Comment: @godonichia It depends on $x$, but if $x=cy$, $y/(y^2+x^2)$ still behaves as some constant multiplied by $1/y$, which is unbounded.

Comment: @godonichia Yes, **some** paths from the unit disk.

Comment: Can u explain about what u r saying ? "some paths"

Comment: @godonichia In the sense, that $(x,y)$ from near every halfline disprove your approximation (and give different limits).

Answer (score 3):

If $|f| \leq g$ and $g \to 1/2$, you **can't** conclude that $f \to 1/2$! You must have $g \to 0$ to conclude.

The limit doesn't exist: pick $y=x$ and compute $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,x)$. Then pick $y=0$ and compute $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x,0)$

Comment: ok thankyou now i see the point !.

Comment: g goes to 1/2 and so f may goes to - infinity as its less than 1/2 and so it maynot exist .is my reasoning right ?

Comment: Well, $f$ may not *go* anywhere: maybe $f$ doesn't have any limit.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is here :
[image]

for $x$ and $y$ tending to $0$, then $\arrowvert{ \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}}\arrowvert$ tends to infinity

$\arrowvert{ \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}}\arrowvert$ is undeterminated

Comment: But i have seen question been proved using this absolute value  of ${ x^{2} / x^{2} + y^{2}}$ $\leq 1 $

Comment: Of course ! But, you did not use x^2/(x^2+y^2)<1 , you use x<(x^2+y^2)<1 which is false. Do not confuse x^2 and x.

Comment: but also $x$ is $\leq $ $x^{2}$ ... so it reduces to that only

Comment: It is not x^2/(x^2+y^2) that you have to consider, but xy/(x^2+y^2) which is equal to 1/((x/y)+(y/x)). When x and y tend to 0, then (y/x) is undeterminate. So, xy/(x^2+y^2) is undeterminate. Of course, xy/(x^2+y^2) can be equal to 0 in some cases(for example if x=0 but with y non equal to zero). Nevertheless, in case x=0 AND y=0 the result is undeterminated.